# How to show Grid line in UniformGrid in code/xaml for WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

I would like to know how to show grid line in UniformGrid for WPF. I know that it is easy to set Grid line in normal Grid, but I find that UniformGrid cannot set Grid line like that of normal Grid. It is good to give simple example for both of code and xaml because I want to be more flexible in programming. Thanks!

```
      // LOGIN PAGE
     //gameType is input by users.If gameType =3, it will form 3x3 uniform grid in GAMEPLAY PAGE
     GamePlay main = new GamePlay(gameType, playerNum); 
     App.Current.MainWindow = main;
     this.Close();
     main.Show();

     // GAMEPLAY PAGE
     // Form the required grid, I can form the grid correctly, but I want grid line to make it more clear
```

Comment: Consider using `Rectangle` as the root element in the `UniformGrid` cell. See [this](http://wrb.home.xs4all.nl/Articles_2011/Article_WPFUniformGrid_01.htm) tutorial

Answer (score -1):

You could always place a Grid with ShowGridLines set to True on top of a UniformGrid.

Something like below:

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
    <UniformGrid Rows="4" Columns="4">

    </UniformGrid>
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Assuming you have a main grid where you want to place your uniformgrid and a grid with lines, the sample code is as below:

```
    int rows = 4;
    int cols = 4;

    var uniformGird = new UniformGrid() {Rows = rows, Columns = cols};
    mainGrid.Children.Add(uniformGird);

    var grid = new Grid()
                    {
                        ShowGridLines = true
                    };
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
    }

    mainGrid.Children.Add(grid);
```

You could wrap the above code in a method and pass rows, cols as method parameters.

Comment: I will pass the value of column and row from other page, so I do not wanna fixed it to 4x4 because the number of column and row are flexible depending on users

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of your application?